# Windows Folder Permission

Tags: windows, directory, permissions

May i check for the below folder rights, is the user able to read files inside of the folder?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to enable "Read" as well. And possible "Read & Execute", too, depending on the contents.

Comment: Doesn't it make it silly to have "Deny Read" checkbox too if not checking the "Allow Read" will have implicitly denied read access.

Comment: @ChinBoon - No problem, I've just made a minor correction. Too early here.

Comment: @ChinBoon - Yes, you should only use "Deny" when you need to override other permissions. Not having any permission to write, and having a deny on write will resolve to the same end result for the user. However, a DENY will override an ALLOW if the user is a member of multiple groups.